# Remove text with event 'replace'

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

I would like to remove some text which says `text` with this code:

```
$(".jq-text li a").html(function(i, h){
     return h.replace(/text/, "");
  });
```

It works good, as expected. The problem is that I would like to remove the text `http://` instead, so I tried:

```
$(".jq-text li a").html(function(i, h){
     return h.replace(/http:///, "");
  });
```

This is giving me an error in dreamweaver...How should I write this?

Comment: you should escape the character "/" like this "\/"

Comment: When the text string you are replacing exists only once, you could simply do this `.replace("http://", "-empty-")` http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/bmFcG/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to escape the forward slashes in your regular expression:

```
return h.replace(/http:\/\//, "");
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to escape the `/` by using `\/`

Try,

```
$(".jq-text li a").html(function(i, h){
     return h.replace(/http:\/\//, "");
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use escaping like this:

```
$(".jq-text li a").html(function(i, h){
     return h.replace(/http:\/\//, "");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why use regex in your expression.

```
return h.replace( "http://", "" );
```

As pointed out this only replaces the first occurrence of *http://*. If this is an issue use:

```
return h.replace( "http://", "", "g" );
```

Comment: That will only replace the 1st instance.  For a non-regex version you should use `split("http://").join("")`